# "npm install <package>" - why do garbage characters appear in console output?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

I am running an out-of-the-box Ubuntu AWS EC2 instance, and when I install Node and then install a package, such as:

```
// It could be any package
sudo npm install mysql
```

... the package installation is successful, but **garbage characters** always appear in the console output.

Here is an example from the above NPM package installation:

```
ubuntu@ip-0-0-0-0:/var/www/html$ sudo npm install mysql
mysql@2.9.0 node_modules/mysql
â”œâ”€â”€ bignumber.js@2.0.7
â””â”€â”€ readable-stream@1.1.13 (core-util-is@1.0.1, string_decoder@0.10.31, isarray@0.0.1, inherits@2.0.1)
```

I have just attempted to find a discussion / answer about **why the above garbage characters appear**, but I cannot find anything.

Note: This has been happening over months, on every Linux instance I've had occasion to install NPM packages on (perhaps 5 - all Ubuntu EC2 instances).  I've just been ignoring the issue, but today I decided to post a question about it.

**Why are garbage characters appearing in the console output when I install any Node package via NPM?**

Comment: What does executing `locale` and `echo $TERM` show?

Comment: `locale` results in `en_US.UTF-8` for all entries except `LANGUAGE` and `LC_ALL`, which are empty (though `LANG` is present); `echo $TERM` results in `vt100`.

Comment: What SSH client are you using? Also, are those `locale` values for the client system or the remote server?

Comment: @mscdex I am using SecureCRT (https://www.vandyke.com/products/securecrt/).  The output from `locale` is what I see on the console when I type the command, but I am using SecureCRT to run the SSH session and provide the view to the console output.